# export: not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, vert.x

This could be something trivial and related to bash!

I am trying to export a system variable named "vertx.mods" and this results in error:

```
# export vertx.mods=/app/mods
bash: export: `vertx.mods=/app/mods': not a valid identifier
```

(bash version 4.3.11(1)-release on Ubuntu 14.04)

Context: This is for [vert.x](http://vertx.io/embedding_manual.html)

> vertx.mods - When looking for or installing non system modules Vert.x
>   will look in the directory mods in the current working directory. If
>   this property is set this will tell Vert.x to instead look in the
>   provided directory.

Comment: @Mat: thanks for the quick response. I need to set this as vert.x expects such a variable! Is there a workaround or is vert.x badly designed?

Comment: Either it's badly designed or you're not reading the docs right. Are you abosutely certain they're asking you to set such an environment variable in your shell and not in some config file somewhere?

Comment: Hmmm... http://vertx.io/embedding_manual.html says `vertx.mods` is a system property

Comment: Java system properties are not shell environment variables. You set them with the `-D` command line flag to the JVM or in configuration files.

Comment: Turns out i was looking at wrong documentation. I need environment variable called `VERTX_MODS` and not `vertx.mods`

Answer (score 0):

In bash, variable names can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscore. The first character can't be a digit. Therefore, dot is invalid in a variable name.